# Does human DNA have markers that Jesus is alive in us?

Tags: science, historical-jesus, biology

The author of the Voyager books, Ashayana Dean, offers a graph that is called Diamond Sun DNA 12 strand Celestial human silicate lineage related to that of Jesus. Can you tell me if modern day humans have carried on this lineage?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, I recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: Ashayana Deane is the author of the Voyagers Series Books, the Kathara Bio-Spiritual Healing System and other publications. She has been personally trained through ritual physical contact since early childhood by the Melchizedek Cloister Priests of Ur. On that basis I vote to have this question closed. Christianity Stack Exchange is for committed Christians.

Answer (score 3):

**Does human DNA have markers that Jesus is alive in us?**

This completely a bogus idea of Ashayana Dean.

Scriptures for most Christians tell us to stay away from mediums.

> 6 “‘I will set my face against anyone who turns to mediums and spiritists to prostitute themselves by following them, and I will cut them off from their people. - [Leviticus 20:6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus%2020%3A6&version=NIV)

Channeling is a method of trying to communicate with the spirit world that has existed since antiquity. Most modern channelers learn the art through the practice of Eastern meditation. Ashayana Deane practices channeling and is thus a medium of occult practices.

> Ashayana Deane was born in 1964 in the United States. She claims to have had contact with extraterrestrial beings since childhood, and to have been trained by them to be a speaker for the Guardian Alliance, a group of benevolent races that protect the Earth and its inhabitants from negative interference. She also claims to have access to ancient records stored on crystal discs that contain the true history and destiny of humanity.
>
> Ashayana Deane has a background in biochemistry, psychology, and metaphysics. She has studied various spiritual traditions, such as Buddhism, Hinduism, Christianity, Judaism, Islam, and Native American spirituality. She has also researched topics such as quantum physics, genetics, astrology, numerology, and sacred geometry. She has synthesized her knowledge and experience into a system of spiritual science that she calls Keylontic Science.
> What is Keylontic Science? - [Who is Ashayana Deane](https://medium.com/broaderinsights/who-is-ashayana-deane-93ccd9dc858c)

Most would not give thought to the idea that human DNA have markers that Jesus is alive in us, any thought as A. Deane describes it as such. This even if it were true would be impossible to scientifically prove.

Comment: Quite so. Anyway, it is the spiritual connection between our Lord and Saviour, Christ Jesus, the Son of God, that counts.  If we have experienced the new birth, and the Holy Spirit indwells us, then we are born-again and have been adopted into His family.

Comment: @Lesley Absolutely